# Fetch/ se if exists, identifier in array

Tags: php, arrays, fetch, exists, identifier

How can I grab the identifier in an array?

Like this example

```
Array
(
    [6] => Stil
    [8] => Färg
    [7] => Material
)
```

I want to fetch the 6, 8 and 7. To fetch "Stil", "Färg" and "Material" it is pretty easy. $arr[6] and so on. But if I want to get or see if the 6, 8 or 7 exists. How do I manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

```
array_search('Stil', $array); // 6
```

Or if the value is the array multiple times, use [`array_keys`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

```
array_keys($array, 'Stil'); // array(0 => 6)
```

UPDATE: If you don't know the value, you can use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
array_key_exists(6, $array); // true
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But if I don't know what "names" are of the arrays like "Stil", "Färg" and "Material"? How do I solve it then?

Comment: @Fredrik: Try [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

Answer (score 1):

as rocket said

or as like that using isset

```
if(isset($var[6])){

    ..........

    }
```